MWAA(airflow) tasks on abnormally on EKS(k8s)
Environments:

MWAA(airflow) 2.8.1
requirements.txt

astronomer-cosmos==1.3.2
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes


EKS(k8s) 1.27

DAG code below:

from pathlib import Path

from airflow import DAG
from pendulum import datetime
from cosmos.config import ProjectConfig

from cosmos import (
    ProfileConfig,
    ExecutionConfig,
    ExecutionMode,
    DbtTaskGroup,
)
from cosmos.profiles import RedshiftUserPasswordProfileMapping
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

PROJECT_DIR = Path("dags/dbt/dbtcicdnew/")


with DAG(
    dag_id="dbtcicdnew",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 27),
    doc_md=__doc__,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:


    run_models = DbtTaskGroup(
        profile_config=ProfileConfig(
            profile_name="dbtcicdnew",
            target_name="dev",
            profile_mapping=RedshiftUserPasswordProfileMapping(
                conn_id="redshift_default",
                profile_args={
                    "schema": "public",
                },
            ),
        ),
        project_config=ProjectConfig(PROJECT_DIR),
        execution_config=ExecutionConfig(
            execution_mode=ExecutionMode.KUBERNETES,
        ),
        operator_args={
            "do_xcom_push": False,
            "project_dir":"/app",
            "image": "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dbtcicdnew:1.0",
            "get_logs": True,
            "is_delete_operator_pod": False,
            "namespace": "mwaa",
            "config_file": "/usr/local/airflow/dags/kubeconfig",
            "in_cluster": False,
            "image_pull_policy": "Always",
        },
    )
    e1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="pre_dbt")
    e2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="post_dbt")
    e1 >> run_models >> e2

trigger to run DAG.Using kubectl get po -A -w to watch task pod below:
NAMESPACE     NAME                                               READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   aws-node-62v44                                     2/2     Running             0          5h48m
kube-system   coredns-6dfd46db99-mszjc                           1/1     Running             0          5h54m
kube-system   coredns-6dfd46db99-xfrls                           1/1     Running             0          5h54m
kube-system   kube-proxy-c8vs2                                   1/1     Running             0          5h48m
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-category-run-4hrk5hmz   0/1     Completed           0          10s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-event-run-94r4a8hr      0/1     Completed           0          9s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-sales-run-6o1no285      0/1     ContainerCreating   0          7s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-users-run-51toaaz5      0/1     Completed           0          7s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-run-ouja4593     0/1     Completed           0          7s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-users-run-51toaaz5      0/1     Completed           0          9s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-run-ouja4593     0/1     Completed           0          9s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-category-run-4hrk5hmz   0/1     Completed           0          12s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-event-run-94r4a8hr      0/1     Completed           0          11s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-users-run-51toaaz5      0/1     Completed           0          9s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-category-run-4hrk5hmz   0/1     Completed           0          12s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-run-ouja4593     0/1     Completed           0          9s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-event-run-94r4a8hr      0/1     Completed           0          11s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-category-run-4hrk5hmz   0/1     Terminating         0          13s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-category-run-4hrk5hmz   0/1     Terminating         0          13s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-event-run-94r4a8hr      0/1     Terminating         0          12s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-event-run-94r4a8hr      0/1     Terminating         0          12s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-users-run-51toaaz5      0/1     Terminating         0          10s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-users-run-51toaaz5      0/1     Terminating         0          10s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-run-ouja4593     0/1     Terminating         0          10s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-run-ouja4593     0/1     Terminating         0          10s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-sales-run-6o1no285      0/1     Completed           0          14s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-sales-run-6o1no285      0/1     Completed           0          15s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-sales-run-6o1no285      0/1     Terminating         0          16s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-sales-run-6o1no285      0/1     Terminating         0          16s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Completed           0          1s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq    0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq    0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq    0/1     Completed           0          1s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Completed           0          2s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5       0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5       0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z      0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z      0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z      0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Completed           0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5       0/1     Completed           0          1s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq    0/1     Completed           0          2s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Terminating         0          4s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-listing-run-rt4ofxra    0/1     Terminating         0          4s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq                   0/1     Terminating         0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-first-dbt-model-test-lapl1fwq                   0/1     Terminating         0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5                      0/1     Completed           0          2s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5                      0/1     Terminating         0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-date-run-qabzl5z5                      0/1     Terminating         0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     Completed           0          1s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     Completed           0          2s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     Terminating         0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-run-7a3me2r9                   0/1     Terminating         0          3s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     Completed           0          13s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     Completed           0          15s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     Terminating         0          15s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-my-second-dbt-model-test-knk3wih3                  0/1     Terminating         0          15s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Completed           0          38s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Completed           0          40s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Completed           0          40s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z                     0/1     Completed           0          41s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Terminating         0          41s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-total-sales-by-event-ru-1envlgl2   0/1     Terminating         0          41s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z                     0/1     Completed           0          43s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z                     0/1     Terminating         0          43s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-base-public-venue-run-b9ke290z                     0/1     Terminating         0          43s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     Pending             0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     Completed           0          0s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     Completed           0          2s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     Terminating         0          2s
mwaa          dbt-task-group-rpt-finance-qtr-top-events-by-sales-run-cjf6gwpq   0/1     Terminating         0          2s

Pod status changes from Pending to Completed takes 0s.
Additional infomations:

dbt project repository

Pod Running normally.
